# How to block/disable swf in firefox?

Tags: firefox, swf

I want block swf (flash) in firefox.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try FlashBlock https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433/

Comment: +1 - a must-have Firefox add-on :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is really programming related but you can get an extension for Firefox that blocks flash animations:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433/